# Superfish menu is not responsive for mobile screens

Tags: 7, navigation

i'm using drupal 7 and superfish 7.x-1.9, the problem is when i reduce the browser, the menu is not responsive, it still be the same nothing moves, i'm working on it for hours now and nothing

Please any help on configurations ?

Here a screenshot of the desktop menu :
[image]

And here the same menu with browser reduced on width :
[image]

Comment: Hide it for mobile and show a mobile menu for mobile

Comment: @J.Reynolds This is exactly what i want to do(keeping the desktop and hide it for mobile AND create a second menu for mobile that is hidden on desktop), but superfish is supposed to be responsive by default, but not for the menu i've created

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation about it being responsive. When I used it in the past I made the text and padding smaller at various breakpoints, then hid it completely at mobile breakpoint. Looj here for alternative: https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_dropdown_menus

Comment: Yes I see @J.Reynolds but from the superfish 2.0 the menu is responsive, so for my version i'm gonna work with custom breakpoints as you said

Answer (score 1):

Superfish has a pretty extensive settings/configuration area, all of which, do take away any necessary programming for menus, and make setting up a complex menu simple.

You are probably missing a mobile declaration somewhere in the settings/config, I would read up on the Superfish documentation here: https://www.drupal.org/node/754652

This also has other useful links that may assist with your situation.